# Detailed status notification in wp without tile

Tags: windows-phone

How can I add a detailed status notification in WP8 without using tiles ?
like What Gabriel did in this [app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=26149e9c-dd27-45c4-9354-08c94d370886)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detailed status notification is pulled directly from the tile. However the tile doesn't need to be visible. So you could have the app show detailed info on the lockscreen without being pinned to the start screen.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207048(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Linkingthelockscreensettingspagefromwithinyourapp

Comment: I did not know that,But In my case I have a custom tile that already contains drawn information and I want to add some other information on the lock screen notification that should not appear on the same tile ofcourse.? I think this is impossible ,Right?

Comment: Interesting! What you could do is create the custom tile as a secondary tile. And then keep the first tile unpinned (if it was pinned it would still show valuable stuff). But having a custom tile connect to the lockscreen sounds hard at the moment.

Comment: So Lockscreen info takes from 1st unpinned and we are still having our 2nd custom tile ,I think this doable ,Thank you Fabian

Comment: Exactly! Good luck in your programming :) And may the bugs be easily crushable ;)